# ffmpeg - How to replace / overwrite part of audio from given timestamp on?

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I am using [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native) to manage audio recordings in React Native.

- I have 2 recordings - `rec_1.m4a` and `rec_2.m4a`.
- I only know the duration of `rec_1.m4a`, which is 10.0 seconds.
- I want to overwrite `rec_1.m4a` with `rec_2.m4a` from a specific timestamp on - e.g. from 5.6 seconds.

How can I do this with ffmpeg?

[There are two special cases:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw1Kz.jpg)

1. `rec_2.m4a` ends before `rec_1.m4a` does (in our case this means `rec_2.m4a`'s duration is <4.4 seconds - 10.0-5.6=4.4).
2. `rec_2.m4a` does not end even after `rec_1.m4a` does (in our case this means `rec_2.m4a`'s duration is >=4.4 seconds).

I know I could split the files and then concatenate them. But for that I would have to know `rec_2.m4a`'s duration, which I don't.

Edit: Figured I could use the [`FFprobeKit.getMediaInformationAsync()`](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native#3-using) function to easily get the duration of `rec_2.m4a`. But it would still be nice to know if replacement is possible without this extra step.